# Debian Buster, Apache2.4, PHP 7.3 FPM / FCGID, vHost, running scripts with different users per vHost

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, php

I'm pretty much lost at the moment. I'm fairly new to Linux and Server Administration, so please don't kill me, if I missed obvious things (I'm sure I did)

situation is as follows:

Goal:

- I'm trying to setup a Webserver (Apache 2.4 on Debian Buster/10) with
  different vHosts which have different directories.
- PHP (PHP 7.3)
  scripts in those directories should be executed by a certain user who
  differs from vHost to vHost

What I tried:

- setting up fastcgi through an old tutorial [Debian-8 fastcgi vHost Php vHost Tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/apache/install-php-fpm-and-apache-on-debian-8/) | which failed due to the fact that Debian Buster/10 doesn't have said module, now they seem to use fcgid, php-fpm worked, but PHP enviroment vars where still
  `Server API FPM/FastCGI
  USER www-data
  HOME /var/www`
- then I tried a different Tutorial [Apache Debian and fcgid in german](https://christophfischer.com/linux/12-apache/47-apache-server-mit-php-fastcgi-und-debian-50-lenny) which changed the enviroment vars of PHP to:
  `PATH   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` (without SuexecUserGroup set)
  or
  `PATH   /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` (with SuexecUserGroup set)
  `Server API CGI/FastCGI
  PHPRC   /etc/php7.3/cgi
  PWD /var/www/domain_path`
  I'm not sure if that is what I want, 'cause the USER and HOME vars are gone and I'm not sure if all of the bin paths should be there except maybe /usr/local/bin?
- I also tried to use mpm-itk module [mpm-itk tutorial](https://cloudkul.com/blog/apache-virtual-hosting-with-different-users/) but that didn't work at all (php file was not served at all), maybe a permission problem, but maybe it's not even what I want.

I'm really lost for now, because I can't figure out how to do this... maybe someone can point me in the right direction or explain where I'm f*in' up (besides lack of knowledge)

Thanks!

EDIT: One of the tutorials is in german

Answer (score 0, accepted):

second tutorial [Apache, Debian, and fcgid (german)](https://christophfischer.com/linux/12-apache/47-apache-server-mit-php-fastcgi-und-debian-50-lenny) worked - checked with php's get_current_user()